# Why No Divide by Zero Exception?

Tags: exception, groovy, logic

Why does this code below not throw a *Devide by Zero Exception*? Rather it returns **Infinity** in Groovy.

```
(((99.0f-0.0f)/(0.0f))*100).round(2)​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same as in Java.
The important point is how Groovy transforms numbers into Objects and handles operators.

`1.0/0` in Groovy throws the `ArithmeticException`, as the numbers are internally used as instances of `BigDecimal` and division operator is implemented as `BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal)` which throws the exception.

`1f/0f` in Groovy as in Java returns `Infinity`, as the numbers are internally used as instances of `Float` as explicitly requested and thus the division operator is the standard Java `/` which returns `Infinity`.

Compare with those two lines in Java

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(1f).divide(new BigDecimal(0f)));
System.out.println(1f/0f);
```

The first will throw `ArithmeticException`, the second returns `Infinity`.